# How to remove this kind of duplication

Tags: c++, templates, dry

I have code like this:

```
struct A1{
    void do_something1(int t, ... ){
        switch(t){
            default:
            case  8: return process_<uint8_t >(a, b, c);
            case 16: return process_<uint16_t>(a, b, c);
            case 32: return process_<uint32_t>(a, b, c);
            case 64: return process_<uint64_t>(a, b, c);
        }
    }
       
    template<typename T>
    void process_(...){
    }
};
    
struct A2{
    void do_something2(int t, ... ){
        switch(t){
            default:
            case  8: return process_<uint8_t >(d, e, f);
            case 16: return process_<uint16_t>(d, e, f);
            case 32: return process_<uint32_t>(d, e, f);
            case 64: return process_<uint64_t>(d, e, f);
        }
    }
       
    template<typename T>
    void process_(...){
    }
};
```

Several classes that have similar switch that "forward" same arguments to another method with template parameter instead of method argument `t`.

At the moment, if I need to change the parameters of `process_` I need to write them 4 times.

Is there an easy way I can remove this duplication?
e.g. instead of 4 almost the same lines, to have just 1-2 lines of code.

```
switch(t){
    default:
    case  8: return process_<uint8_t >(d, e, f);
    case 16: return process_<uint16_t>(d, e, f);
    case 32: return process_<uint32_t>(d, e, f);
    case 64: return process_<uint64_t>(d, e, f);
}
```

I can think about pointer to method, but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: If you can, replacing the `t` parameter with an `enum` would help, otherwise you know someone's going to accidentally pass something like `6` instead of `16`. At that point you could use the `enum` as an index into an array of function pointers.

Comment: in this specific code, I use uint8_t for default.
in production code I made it better - emitting an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a helper function to "promote" the runtime value `t` into one of the four types, passing it to a lambda:

```cpp
// C++20 version
template<typename Lambda>
decltype(auto) select_type(int t, const Lambda& l) {
    switch (t) {
        default:
        case 8 : return l.template operator()<std::uint8_t >();
        case 16: return l.template operator()<std::uint16_t>();
        case 32: return l.template operator()<std::uint32_t>();
        case 64: return l.template operator()<std::uint64_t>();
    }
}


void do_something1(int t, ... ) {
    select_type(t, [&]<typename T> {
        process_<T>(a, b, c);
    });
}
```

```cpp
// C++14/17 version
template<typename T>
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename Lambda>
auto select_type(int t, const Lambda& l) -> decltype(l(type_identity<std::uint8_t>{})) {
    switch (t) {
        default:
        case 8 : return l(type_identity<std::uint8_t >{});
        case 16: return l(type_identity<std::uint16_t>{});
        case 32: return l(type_identity<std::uint32_t>{});
        case 64: return l(type_identity<std::uint64_t>{});
    }
}

void do_something1(int t, ... ) {
    select_type(t, [&](auto t) {
        using T = typename decltype(t)::type;
        process_<T>(a, b, c);
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you really need the `type_identity` helper in the C++14/17 version? Couldn't you just do something like this instead? `l(std::uint8_t{}); l(std::uint16_t{}); ... [&](auto t) { process_<decltype(t)>(a, b, c); }` Either way, your `switch`es are suffering from fallthrough, whereas the `switch`es in the OP's original code don't, so you will have to add `break`s or `return`s to your example.

Comment: I did not know lambda templates are available in C++14. Thanks a lot !

Comment: yes, was bug with goldbolt

Comment: @Nick templated lambdas were added in C++20, but `auto` parameters were added to lambdas in C++14.

Comment: Yes, all OK, I can see how you do it, you pass type_identity<T> into a lambda - this is what I missed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is adapted from a general "promote" pattern which is usually `int x, auto lambda` -> `lambda(std::integral_constant<int, x>{})`, replacing the integral_constant with type_identity (I think there's a boost library that does this?). The typed 0s would definitely work but it's less obvious (especially since `[&](int t)` would work unintentionally). I've fixed the fallthroughs though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I can think about pointer to method, but I am not sure how to do it.

Something like this should work:

```
int whichOne(int t) {
    switch(t){
        default:
        case  8: return 0;
        case 16: return 1;
        case 32: return 2;
        case 64: return 3;
    }
}

struct A1{
    template<typename T>
    void process_(...){
    }

    void do_something1(int t, ...){
        using MethodType = void (A1::*)(...);
        static const MethodType methods[] = {
            &A1::process_<uint8_t >,
            &A1::process_<uint16_t>,
            &A1::process_<uint32_t>,
            &A1::process_<uint64_t>
        };
        (this->*methods[whichOne(t)])(a, b, c);
    }
};
    
struct A2{
    template<typename T>
    void process_(...){
    }

    void do_something2(int t, ...){
        using MethodType = void (A2::*)(...);
        static const MethodType methods[] = {
            &A2::process_<uint8_t >,
            &A2::process_<uint16_t>,
            &A2::process_<uint32_t>,
            &A2::process_<uint64_t>
        };
        (this->*methods[whichOne(t)])(d, e, f);
    }
};
```